# XML frequency count

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count, frequency

```
<result name="test">
   <cpu_time>  45346.23 </cpu_time>
   <max_mem>      1104 MB</max_mem>
</result>
<result name="error_test">
   <cpu_time>   5300.80 </cpu_time>
   <max_mem>      1059 MB</max_mem>
</result>
```

I have a the above XML file, I need to count the number of times `<cpu_time>` entries 
which have values less than 3600 in XSLT. Here is the XSLT so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(result/cpu_time) &lt; 3600" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XML sample you provided is broken (not well-formed). Unless you fix it, all answers will be vague.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(result[number(cpu_time) &lt; 3600])" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (on [www.xslfiddle.net](http://www.xslfiddle.net))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(result/cpu_time[. &lt; 3600])" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you need a single root element for XML, and your node names are mismatched (I added a root element named "root", and made all of the child elements 'result' for testing.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, this helps me. How do I code something like which could provide the count the entries in between certain value : Example like cpu_time &lt 7200 and &gt 3600.

Comment: You can use infix `and`, like this: `count(result/cpu_time[. &lt; 7200 and . &gt; 3600])`

Comment: Or do I need to use something like "count(result/cpu_time[. &lt; 7200])" - "count(result/cpu_time[. &lt; 3600])"